# MariaDB as destination permission required in AWS SCT

Tags: mariadb, aws-sct

We are using AWS SCT tool to migrate Oracle database to MariaDB.

We have given the required permission on Oracle database after reading from below

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html

Haven't find the what are permission required in MariaDB as target. Found MariaDB as source https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.Connecting

We are able to add Oracle as source in AWS SCT but while adding MariaDB as target we are getting below error :

```
The specified account (testPermission) does not have sufficient privileges for working with the following object(s):
MariaDB Server : [SELECT, SHOW VIEW]
```

Permission on MariaDB (output of SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();)

```
 GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `<username>`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<password>'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `<databasename>`.* TO `<username>`@`%`
```

Can you help me here what extra permission required in MariaDB?

Thanks in advance.